# Newline not working in javascript google map label

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The code below puts a label on a polygon and works fine except for the newline. The variables in the text are c# and they work fine as well. For some reason I just cannot get the newline to work. It compiles but everything shows on the same line.

```
var AustinLabel = new MapLabel({
                    text: "<%=zipCentroid[i]%>" + "\n" + "<%=colorCount[i]%>" + "<%=layerType%>", 
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(<%=zipLat[i]%>, <%=zipLong[i]%>),
                    map: map,
                    fontSize: 30,
                    minZoom: 13,
                    fontColor: "#FFFFFF",
                    strokeColor: "#000000"
                });
                AustinLabel.set('position', new google.maps.LatLng(<%=zipLat[i]%>, <%=zipLong[i]%>));
```

Comment: Infowindows and other elements of google maps use html markup. Use <br />

Comment: I have tried"<%=zipCentroid[i]%>" + <br /> + "<%=colorCount[i]%>" + "<%=layerType%>", and that did does not work. if I put <br /> in quotes it just shows up as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The google maps MapLabel object uses the HTML5 canvas fillText() method which doen't support multi line text.

https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/maplabel/src/maplabel.js?r=300

You may want to consider using an InfoWindow instead. Here's the documentation for the InfoWindow:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow

```
var AustinLabel = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: "<%=zipCentroid[i]%>" + "<br/>" + "<%=colorCount[i]%>" + "<%=layerType%>", 
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(<%=zipLat[i]%>, <%=zipLong[i]%>)
                });
```

Comment: My project requires that I use plain text on the polygon so I cannot use info window. I may have to draw multiple labels for each line instead. Thanks for the information

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<BR>
```

as it uses html markup, or use css to create the break.

Comment: I think you have a mistype

Answer (score 0):

From : [Multiline / Wrap Text Support - GitHub](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label/issues/8)

---

Way 1:

To get multiline support, add this:

```
MapLabel.prototype.wrapText = function(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight) {
  var words = text.split(' ');
  var line = '';

  for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
    var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
    var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
    var testWidth = metrics.width;
    if (testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) {
      context.strokeText(line, x, y);
      context.fillText(line, x, y);

      line = words[n] + ' ';
      y += lineHeight;
    }
    else {
      line = testLine;
    }
  }
  context.strokeText(line, x, y);
  context.fillText(line, x, y);
};
```

In drawCanvas_, change

```
if (strokeWeight) {
  ctx.lineWidth = strokeWeight;
  ctx.strokeText(text, strokeWeight, strokeWeight);
}

ctx.fillText(text, strokeWeight, strokeWeight);
```

to

```
if (strokeWeight) {
  ctx.lineWidth = strokeWeight;

}

this.wrapText(ctx, text, strokeWeight, strokeWeight, *ADD MAX WIDTH*, *ADD LINEHEIGHT*);
//e.g.  this.wrapText(ctx, text, strokeWeight, strokeWeight, 200, 14);
```

This code is an extension of:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-wrap-text-tutorial/

---

Way 2:

Replace:

```
if (strokeWeight) {
   ctx.lineWidth = strokeWeight;
   ctx.strokeText(text, strokeWeight, strokeWeight);
}

ctx.fillText(text, strokeWeight, strokeWeight);
```

with

```
if (strokeWeight) {
   ctx.lineWidth = strokeWeight;
  // ctx.strokeText(text, strokeWeight, strokeWeight);
}
    // ctx.fillText(text, strokeWeight, strokeWeight);
    var lineheight = 15;
    var lines = text.split('\n');

for (var i = 0; i<lines.length; i++) {
   ctx.fillText(lines[i], strokeWeight, strokeWeight + (i * lineheight));
   if (strokeWeight) {
        ctx.lineWidth = strokeWeight;
        ctx.strokeText(lines[i], strokeWeight, strokeWeight + (i * lineheight));
      }
}
```