# How can I make multi line label on google maps when using chrome?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I’m making a system which shows the marker with text(status,price,owner  of apartments). 
I haved tested it on IE using label text.
It used to work fine with /n to break a line.
But when I changed to chrome browser, label text’s /n doesnt’ work at all....  I want this label text to be multi line.
Is there anyone who have an idea?

I want to print label with 3 lines aaaaaaa bbbb cccc

But this doesn’t work:

```
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
  title:"A\nBa", 
  position: {
    lat: 12.975688, 
    lng: 77.640812
  }, 
  label: {
    text:"aaaaaaa \n bbbb \n cccc"
  }, 
  icon: { 
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE, 
    fillColor: "green", 
    strokeColor: "green", 
    fillOpacity: 1.0, 
    scale: 20
  }, 
  map: map
});
```

Comment: instead of \n you must use html's <br/>

Comment: @HastaTamang <br/> doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15469227/864635

Answer (score -2):

One option would be to use the third party [`MarkerWithLabel`](https://github.com/geocodezip/v3-utility-library/blob/master/packages/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js) utility library.  That supports HTML tags in its `labelContent` field (and CSS styling of the `labelContent`)

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
  position: bangalore,
  labelContent: "A<br/>B",
  labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(2, 12),
  icon: {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillColor: "red",
    strokeColor: "red",
    fillOpacity: 1.0,
    scale: 20
  },
  map: map
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5v7w0c68/5/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var bangalore = {
    lat: 12.97,
    lng: 77.59
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: bangalore
  });
  var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: bangalore,
    labelContent: "aaaaaaa <br/> bbbb <br/> cccc",
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 20),
    labelStyle: {
      textAlign: "center"
    },
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      fillColor: "red",
      strokeColor: "red",
      fillOpacity: 1.0,
      scale: 20
    },
    map: map
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/geocodezip/v3-utility-library/packages/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
```